# Snapshot pattern: how to represent colection properties?

Tags: design-patterns, snapshot

I'm taking a look at the [Snapshot Design Pattern](https://www.jamestharpe.com/snapshot-pattern/) as a strategy to guarantee that my database is immutable (only inserts should be allowed). When looking at simple properties (ie, 1-1), the strategy presented on the link makes sense (ie, `Firstname` and `Lastname`. However, what's the recommended approach for mapping collections? For instance, suppose that `Customer` has a collection of `Contact` objects (which are value objects). When using regular tables, then we'd have 2 tables: one for `Customer` (one line for each customer) and another for `Contact` (one or more lines for each customer).

When applying the Snapshot pattern, we transform the `Customer` table into 2 (ex.: `Customer` and `CustomerDetails`). What's the recommended transformation for the `Contact` table? Should the contacts be serialized into a single line (say, by using json) so that the `Contact` tables "behaves" like the `CustomerDetails` table?

Thanks.